# How to test the shadowsocks whether works fine in the installed server?

Tags: linux, centos, shadowsocks

How to test the shadowsocks whether works fine in the installed server?

I use the CentOS7.2 installed the `shadowsocks` in it and start it.

```
pip3 install shadowsocks
vi /etc/shadowsocks.json
# start the service
(ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start &)
```

I can use `ps` to find the ssserver:

```
# ps -ef | grep ssserver
root      4107  3881  0 14:06 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssser
root     28270     1  0 8月07 ?       00:00:00 /usr/local/python3/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/python3/bin/ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start
```

But I can not use the shadowrocet to connect it. so how can I test in the server whether it is connectable?